# Сочетаемость слов

Tags: сочетаемость

Можно ли сказать Могучая мощь?

Answer (score 1):

Однако как литературный прием он может вполне быть оправдан .Напр.: <<...И тут и там  вся сила и могучая мощь русского народа.(Виктор Михайлович Васнецов. Биография).

София, поищите в Яндексе. Ссылку дать не могу, слишком громоздкая получается.

Comment: Нацкорпус отверг вашу "могучую" мощь, но нашел две "несокрушимых", обе из советского периода. Также нашлась грозная мощь.

Comment: Дело не в ссылке. Что такое вообще - "могучая мощь"? Новой семантики нет, тавтология присутствует, а особой образности я не вижу. Может быть, Васнецов только картины писал хорошо?

Answer (score 0):

Могучая мощь - это тавтология, повтор однокоренных слов, поэтому так говорить нельзя.

Можно   сказать - несокрушимая мощь.

Comment: Вы так говорите, как будто тавтология это плохо.

Comment: Тавтология плоха, когда это повторение, не уточняющее смысла и обычно являющееся речевой небрежностью. В то же время тавтология может  быть литературным приемом, усиливающим эмоциональное воздействие речи, например: "И одна в пустоте порожней подорожная нам дана" (Цветаева). Впрочем, все зависит от текста. У Васнецова мне это выражение не нравится, для его применения, как мне кажется, нужны повтор, декламация, что-то вроде: "Это и мощь могучая, и сила несокрушимая...", то есть стиль другой. Так что с такими словами нужно обращаться особенно внимательно.

Comment: Несогласный с моим мнением коллега, пожалуйста, поясните, свою точку зрения: можно ли было сказать, к примеру, так: "СССР ―  мировая держава, и его могучая мощь ― реальный фактор мира". Слово "мощь" происходит от слова "мочь" (изначально "мошть", где Т - суффикс, затем чередование ШТ/Щ). Поэтому "могучий и мощный" - это обладающий силой, мощью. Мы имеем повтор, который уместен  в художественных текстах как особый прием.